# How can I incorporate Spring Boot into an Eclipse Plug-in project?

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, webserver, equinox

I have built an eclipse plug-in project which uses `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` to run the entry point method in a class called, `public class Application implements IApplication`. Yes, the project uses `org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication` to essentially build a headless application. I have created a launch configuration for this project which runs the application successfully. Do note that this project runs the eclipse platform (see code below).

So, while the eclipse platform is running, I also want a web server to run (for example Spring Boot). I have noticed, however, that Spring Boot and most other Java web server frameworks have to be initialised from a main function. How can I run both my plug-in project (which runs the eclipse platform) and incorporate a running web server from Spring Boot?

The code below shows what I have now. I want to know what I can add or even change to my project to incorporate a web server.

Here is the Application.java file:

```
// I have removed the package line of code (e.g com.example.test)
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext;

public class Application implements IApplication {

    @Override
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        Path programDirectory;
        try {
            programDirectory = Paths.get(org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL().toURI()).toAbsolutePath();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to determine the location of the software: " + org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL().toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
        }
        
        // Run application (JUST RUNS AN EXTERNAL METHOD)
        HandleSubmission.handleSubmissionMain(programDirectory);
        
        Thread.sleep(100);
        
        return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // Nothing to do
    }

}
```

Here is the Activator.java file:

```
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    private static BundleContext context;

    static BundleContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = bundleContext;
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = null;
    }

}
```

I tried to create a separate java file called SpringBootApp.java which holds the logic and server code for Spring Boot. I did of course import the Spring Boot dependencies into the plugin project. Then, I called the method: SpringBootApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class) in the start method of Application.java (the one which is the entry point to the plugin project). This showed errors such as "Failed to initialise embedded tomcat", or, "Child component failed".

Comment: What were you intending to serve using Spring Boot? Spring Boot isn't a web server, it embeds web servers like Tomcat or Undertow to offer services. Unless you literally want Spring Boot and its dependencies in there somehow, you can probably get by with Jetty directly embedded and spun off onto its own Thread.

Comment: I was trying to make it so that a client would be able to run functions inside my eclipse plugin. For this, I need a web server which would receive those requests.

Comment: Have you looked at this?: https://docs.spring.io/spring-osgi/docs/current/reference/html/app-deploy.html